# Domain issue with D3 using d3.min

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphics

I'm having a problem with the min and max functions of D3, when I use them for my domain, they just seem to work buggy, the max takes just the value bellow the maximum, same happens inverted on min. Or at least this is what it seems, because my graph lacks the superior and inferior maximums. For now I patched it manually(just passing the interval) but next week I'm using hundreds of datasets, so I need to do it properly automatically, thanks in advance, here is my failed axis code:

EDIT: It works very buggy, with some sets works, other not, and in those others, I don't know why, added to the range failure, it inverts the Y axis. I'm pretty sure that my mistake is on de yRange calculus, but I don't know where exactly.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Causa básica</title>
<style>
 .axis path, .axis line
        {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #777;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .axis text
        {
            font-family: 'Arial';
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        .tick
        {
            stroke-dasharray: 1, 2;
        }
        .bar
        {
            fill: FireBrick;
        }
</style>
<svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
InitChart();

function InitChart() {

var lineData;
        d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(data) {
        seeData(data);  
        //d3.tsv("data2.tsv", function(data) {
        //seeData(data);  
        });
function seeData(lineData) {
  var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
    WIDTH = 1000,
    HEIGHT = 500,

    MARGINS = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([2008,
            //d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
        //return d.x;
      //}),
      d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
    ]),
   // yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0.079,0.13]), this works, but is manual
        yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
        return d.y;
      }),
      d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
        return d.y;
      })
    ]),


    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xRange)
      .tickSize(5)
      .tickSubdivide(true),

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yRange)
      .tickSize(5)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSubdivide(true);



  vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);

  var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) {
    return xRange(d.x);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return yRange(d.y);
  })
  .interpolate('linear');

vis.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  //acabar
    .on('click', function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
        if(d3.select(this).attr("stroke")!= "red"){ d3.select(this) .attr("stroke", "red")}
        else {d3.select(this) .attr("stroke", "blue")
                d3.select(this) .attr("stroke-width", 3);}
    })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("stroke", "green")
      .attr("stroke-width", 9);
  })

  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)

        .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3);
  });
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Are your `d.y` strings by any chance and should be numbers?

Comment: Yes, they should be numbers, are you sure they're string? I'm a little disoriented in javascript typing, i thought that min and max must return numbres,  not strings, how can i make a casting here? Thanks!

Comment: Try `+d.y` instead of `d.y`. I'm just guessing here as you haven't given us any information about your data or how it is obtained.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the data is just numbers of mortality in hospitals, something like 2.3566e -2, taken from a TSV file, if you need the entire code or the datafile, just ask for it. Thanks

Comment: And you're converting the strings from the TSV to numbers?

Comment: Data from tsv is String? I didn't know about that, how can i do a casting?

Comment: Just add a `+` in front of the value.

Comment: It's doing the same again, I'm putting my code on the question, i don't know why it fails.

Comment: I just edited and I added the full code to the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're not converting the values. As I've said, try `+d.y` instead of `d.y`.

Comment: As I said, I tried putting '+'  that way, and happened exactly the same. The data is loaded right, the points in the plot are correct, but the domain shown is not the correct one in some plots, and it is in some others. If force it manually it works, but that's the problem, I need this automatic because I'll be plotting hundreds of sets.

Comment: Right, it worked, thanks, I tried this before, but I forgot to put '+' in one of the d.y values, that's the reason it didn't worked, thank you very much  Lars Kotthoff, it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading strings from the TSV file and not converting them to numbers. This means that "10" will be less than "9" (because "1" comes before "9"). To fix, simply convert the strings to numbers using `+`, in particular, use `+d.y` instead of `d.y`.